# Best way to maintain a List of Business Objects in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, wcf

So this question is not so much technical but more sort of conceptual.

I have some experience with asp.net but just started with WPF with WCF services   (no experience whatsoever in winforms). Say I need to maintain this list of Business Objects. I am thinking on 2 solutions:

1. I bind a grid to my List of objects and allow user to edit the objects committing the object when user changes the focused line in the grid if there is no validation errors. If there is validation errors user cannot change the focused line.
2. Allow users to edit freely the list of objects and commit the whole collection doing a batch update on those objects through a save button. Commit is only possible if no validation errors occur in the grid. Validation problems are signalled on the grid and users can freely change the focused row.

What is the standard (best) way of doing this? Any other suggestions welcomed.

Thanks in advance

PS:Just a note, the Datasource is not local to the application the WCF services are being hosted in a web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't say there is a specific "standard" here.  The method that you use will depend greatly on a number of factors.

1. What is the user base?  Is there a high potential for concurrent edits where saving record by record would help reduce potential for collisions?
2. What is the most efficient from the users perspective, do they need to "mass edit" or is it important for them to get each one right before continuing
3. What about lost changes, if you do mass edit, what do you do if the users machine fails, or something causes the application to die.

Comment: Good point about concurrency...although this bit of the application wont have that problem since it's a restricted area. Good point on 3 as well. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on a lot of things, but since you mentioned WCF services, I am going to assume you have a single data source which is exposed to multiple clients by your service interface (right?). In this case you probably want to minimize network traffic, so I would suggest to go for the batch update approach. Otherwise you are going to have service calls for each change any user makes.

If users have a local data source you might want to consider the first approach, since this minimizes the chances for loss of data, since each change is committed to the data source.

Additionally, you might want to look into the WPF datagrid built-in validation capabilities:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee622975.aspx

Comment: The datasource is not local. Question has been edited. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you implement a prototype of a grid that doesn't let you focus to a new row until you've fixed the validation errors in the current row you'll be surprised by how unbelievably irritating using it turns out to be.

There's a third approach you haven't mentioned, which is to update on validation and to allow the user to leave rows in an invalid state.  As long as the UI is quite clear about whether or not a row is valid, there should be no confusion in the user's mind as to whether or not his edits have been committed to the data source.